# How can i get sectionid

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a small generator to improve my skills in developing skills, however i got little problem. How can i get variable sectionid from hidden input with jquery? I try this way, but this doesn't work. I get an undefined value.

```
var sectionid = $(this).find(".sectioncolor").next().val();
alert(sectionid);
```

```js
$("#add_section").on("click", function() {

  var sectionid = $(".section").length;
  var sectionwidth = prompt("Section width");
  var sectionheight = prompt("Section height");
  var bg = prompt("BG color");
  var sectioncolor = prompt("Text color");
  $("#new_section").append('<div class="section" style="width: ' + sectionwidth + 'px; min-height: ' + sectionheight + 'px; background: #' + bg + '; color: #' + sectioncolor + ';"><button type="button" class="add_text">Add text</button><input type="hidden" name="section[' + sectionid + '][\'sectionwidth\']" value="' + sectionwidth + '" /> <input type="hidden" name="section[' + sectionid + '][\'sectionheight\']" value="' + sectionheight + '" /> <input type="hidden" name="section[' + sectionid + '][\'bg\']" value="' + bg + '" /> <input type="hidden" name="section[' + sectionid + '][\'sectioncolor\']" class="sectioncolor" value="' + sectioncolor + '" /> <input type="hidden" class="sectionid" name="sectionid" value="' + sectionid + '" /></div>');

  if ($(".sekcja").length > 0) {
    $("#default-section").css("display", "none");
  }

  if (sectionwidth < 1050) {
    $(".section").css("float", "left");
  }

});

$("#new_section").on("click", ".add_text", function() {

  var sectionid = $(this).find(".sectioncolor").next().val();
  alert(sectionid);
  var inputid = $('.sample').length;
  var inputwidth = prompt("Input width");
  $(this).parent().append('<input type="text" class="sample" style="width: ' + inputwidth + 'px;" placeholder="Sample text..." name="section[' + sectionid + '][\'input\'][' + inputid + '][\'inputtext\']"/><input type="hidden" name="section[' + sectionid + '][\'input\'][' + inputid + '][\'inputwidth\']" value="' + inputwidth + '" />');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="new_section">
  <div id="default-section">Default section</div>
</div>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<button type="button" id="add_section">Add section</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why complicate things ? you can only use `siblings()` for this because you know the class of the element you are looking for

`var sectionid = $(this).siblings(".sectionid").val();`

`find()` searches inside the element , but `sectionid` is a sibling of `add_text` that's why you should use siblings. It's the most direct path to the desired element

```js
$("#add_section").on("click", function() {

  var sectionid = $(".section").length;
  var sectionwidth = prompt("Section width");
  var sectionheight = prompt("Section height");
  var bg = prompt("BG color");
  var sectioncolor = prompt("Text color");
  $("#new_section").append('<div class="section" style="width: ' + sectionwidth + 'px; min-height: ' + sectionheight + 'px; background: #' + bg + '; color: #' + sectioncolor + ';"><button type="button" class="add_text">Add text</button><input type="hidden" name="section[' + sectionid + '][\'sectionwidth\']" value="' + sectionwidth + '" /> <input type="hidden" name="section[' + sectionid + '][\'sectionheight\']" value="' + sectionheight + '" /> <input type="hidden" name="section[' + sectionid + '][\'bg\']" value="' + bg + '" /> <input type="hidden" name="section[' + sectionid + '][\'sectioncolor\']" class="sectioncolor" value="' + sectioncolor + '" /> <input type="hidden" class="sectionid" name="sectionid" value="' + sectionid + '" /></div>');

  if ($(".sekcja").length > 0) {
    $("#default-section").css("display", "none");
  }

  if (sectionwidth < 1050) {
    $(".section").css("float", "left");
  }

});

$("#new_section").on("click", ".add_text", function() {

  var sectionid = $(this).siblings(".sectionid").val();
  alert(sectionid);
  var inputid = $('.sample').length;
  var inputwidth = prompt("Input width");
  $(this).parent().append('<input type="text" class="sample" style="width: ' + inputwidth + 'px;" placeholder="Sample text..." name="section[' + sectionid + '][\'input\'][' + inputid + '][\'inputtext\']"/><input type="hidden" name="section[' + sectionid + '][\'input\'][' + inputid + '][\'inputwidth\']" value="' + inputwidth + '" />');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="new_section">
  <div id="default-section">Default section</div>
</div>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<button type="button" id="add_section">Add section</button>
```

Option2 . if you really want to use `sectioncolor` you can also use `siblings`

`var sectionid = $(this).siblings(".sectioncolor").next().val();`

Answer (score 0):

`sectioncolor` is inside the `div` and not inside `.add_text`, so you need to change:

`var sectionid = $(this).find(".sectioncolor").next().val();`

to

`var sectionid = $(this).parent().find(".sectioncolor").next().val();`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#add_section").on("click", function() {

            var sectionid = $(".section").length;
            alert(sectionid);
            var sectionwidth = prompt("Section width");
            var sectionheight = prompt("Section height");
            var bg = prompt("BG color");
            var sectioncolor = prompt("Text color");
            $("#new_section").append('<div class="section" style="width: '+ sectionwidth +'px; min-height: '+ sectionheight +'px; background: #'+ bg +'; color: #'+ sectioncolor +';"><button type="button" class="add_text">Add text</button><input type="hidden" class="sectionid" name="sectionid" value="'+ sectionid +'" /><input type="hidden" name="section['+sectionid+'][\'sectionwidth\']" value="'+sectionwidth+'" /> <input type="hidden" name="section['+sectionid+'][\'sectionheight\']" value="'+sectionheight+'" /> <input type="hidden" name="section['+sectionid+'][\'bg\']" value="'+bg+'" /> <input type="hidden" name="section['+sectionid+'][\'sectioncolor\']" class="sectioncolor" value="'+sectioncolor+'" /> </div>');

            if ($(".sekcja").length > 0) {
                $("#default-section").css("display","none");    
            }

            if(sectionwidth < 1050) {
                $(".section").css("float","left");  
            }

        });

        $("#new_section").on("click", ".add_text", function() {

                var sectionid = $(this).next().val();
                alert(sectionid);
                var inputid = $('.sample').length;
                var inputwidth = prompt("Input width");
                $(this).parent().append('<input type="text" class="sample" style="width: '+ inputwidth +'px;" placeholder="Sample text..." name="section['+sectionid+'][\'input\']['+inputid+'][\'inputtext\']"/><input type="hidden" name="section['+sectionid+'][\'input\']['+inputid+'][\'inputwidth\']" value="'+inputwidth+'" />');

        });
        });
```

Comment: I hope this will help you .

Comment: `$(this).next().val()` will get the next input value which is `sectionwidth` input. That's not what the op is searching for. Also, when posting an answer you should post is as a snippet ( working code with visible result ) . And also some explanation

Comment: Copy whole code  . I have made changes in html also and then check .

Answer (score -1):

```js
$("#add_section").on("click", function() {
   
   var sectionid = $(".section").length;
   var sectionwidth = prompt("Section width");
   var sectionheight = prompt("Section height");
   var bg = prompt("BG color");
   var sectioncolor = prompt("Text color");
   $("#new_section").append('<div class="section" style="width: '+ sectionwidth +'px; min-height: '+ sectionheight +'px; background: #'+ bg +'; color: #'+ sectioncolor +';"><button type="button" class="add_text">Add text</button><input type="hidden" name="section['+sectionid+'][\'sectionwidth\']" value="'+sectionwidth+'" /> <input type="hidden" name="section['+sectionid+'][\'sectionheight\']" value="'+sectionheight+'" /> <input type="hidden" name="section['+sectionid+'][\'bg\']" value="'+bg+'" /> <input type="hidden" name="section['+sectionid+'][\'sectioncolor\']" class="sectioncolor" value="'+sectioncolor+'" /> <input type="hidden" class="sectionid" name="sectionid" value="'+ sectionid +'" /></div>');
   
   if ($(".sekcja").length > 0) {
    $("#default-section").css("display","none"); 
   }

   if(sectionwidth < 1050) {
    $(".section").css("float","left"); 
   }

  });
  
  $("#new_section").on("click", ".add_text", function() {
    
    var sectionid = $(this).parent(".section").find(".sectioncolor").val();
    alert(JSON.stringify(sectionid));
    var inputid = $('.sample').length;
    var inputwidth = prompt("Input width");
    $(this).parent().append('<input type="text" class="sample" style="width: '+ inputwidth +'px;" placeholder="Sample text..." name="section['+sectionid+'][\'input\']['+inputid+'][\'inputtext\']"/><input type="hidden" name="section['+sectionid+'][\'input\']['+inputid+'][\'inputwidth\']" value="'+inputwidth+'" />');
    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="new_section">
<div id="default-section">Default section</div>
</div>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<button type="button" id="add_section">Add section</button>
```